# How to remove value where not in array in multidimensional array value PHP

Tags: php

This is $multidimensional data result :

```
[
    {
        "2018-11-02": [
            "2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "2018-11-02": [
            "8",
            "3"
        ]
    }
    {
        "2018-11-21": [
            "11",
            "35",
            "94",
            "98",
            "163"
        ]
    },
]
```

`$filter = [3,98,11]`

How to remove object and value in `$multidimensional` where value not exist in `$filter` and after unset, the result will be turned into an object like the one below :

```
{
  "3": 2018-11-02,
  "98": 2018-11-21,
  "11" : 2018-11-21
}
```

In my case, I am using unserialize :

```
for($w=0;$w<count($multidimensional);$w++) {
      $hasilId2[] = (object) [
        $multidimensional[$w]->date=> unserialize($multidimensional[$w]->invoiceid)
      ];
    }
```

I've already try using loop :

```
foreach($multidimensional as $key => $value) {
      if(!in_array($key, $filter)) {
        unset($multidimensional[$key]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: What should happen if a number is contained in multiple dates? What should happen if a filter value does not exist in the array? Also please present your attempt of solving it.

Comment: If a number exists on multiple dates it will create the same object with different numbers
and the same date.
If the filter value does not exist, it will delete the object, and will only get the id and date
available in the filter

So the main goal is to change the multidimensional value $ to a key in the new variable with
Fill in the value of the date that is in $ multidimensional, like the example result that I expect below

Comment: In my case, I am usingI unserialize, i've already update my question, the present my attemnt of soling it

Comment: Can you adjust your question with an example that shows the result with both cases (One multiple and one does not exist)? I'd need to see exactly how it should look, because I dont think I understand what *" create the same object with different numbers"* means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a loop for the main array and a loop for the internal arrays

So it is better to put 2 loop inside each other

There is also no need to uset

You can put the correct results in a separate variable and then use it

You wanted the key to that array to be the final array value

So I used the key function to get the array key and gave the new value like this:

```
$result[array value] = [array key];
```

And finally I printed the new array:

```
$multidimensional = [
    [
        "2018-11-02" => [
            "2"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "2018-11-02" => [
            "8",
            "3"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "2018-11-21" => [
            "11",
            "35",
            "94",
            "98",
            "163"
        ]
    ],
];

$filter = [3, 98, 11];
$result = [];
foreach ($multidimensional as $val1) {
    foreach (array_values($val1)[0] as $key => $val2) {
        if (in_array($val2, $filter)) {
            $result[$val2] = key($val1);
        }
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [3] => 2018-11-02
    [11] => 2018-11-21
    [98] => 2018-11-21
)
```

Comment: thank you very much, your answer really helped me I get a new lesson from your answer.
Thankyou